# System.IO.File.Create is returning System.UnauthorizedAccessException but just for one file

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, system.io.file

**Background**

I have the some c# code that queries sharepoint and then provides the ability to download specific files into a folder on the local computer.

The strange this is that when I try downloading file A, it works no problems.  When i try downloading file B, 2 weird things happen:

1. the "exists" variable always comes back as true - eventhough a local copy of the file doesn't exist.
2. when i click on the option to replace the local file, when it hits the .Create() method, it throws the System.UnauthorizedAccessException error ...

So specifically, when I try to download:

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\d87c4dcd-a0b6-4d3e-a529-72da28f897e4_4p54yvdgfzqvw\LocalState\ABCDoc.docx

It works fine.

When I try to download

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\d87c4dcd-a0b6-4d3e-a529-72da28f897e4_4p54yvdgfzqvw\LocalState\123Doc.docx

I always get the message box that says the file already exists, do i want to replace.  I'll click on yes.  Then it fails with the unauthorized access error.

**What I've tried**

When running in debug mode, I hijack the name of the file and change it to a new name, the download /save works.

**Here's the code:**

```
  protected async void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
        if (menuItem != null)
        {
            //grab the details of the file currently selected 
            var selectedFile = (Microsoft.Graph.ListItem)menuItem.BindingContext;
            
            //check if the file already exists in the local workspace.  if it does prompt.  if not just download. 
            var driveItemPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), selectedFile.DriveItem.Name);
            var exists = System.IO.File.Exists(driveItemPath);
            if (exists)
            {
                if (!await DisplayAlert("Download", "Download and replace local copy of " + selectedFile.DriveItem.Name + "?", "Yes", "No"))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                using (var stream = await App.GraphClient.Sites[siteID].Drive.Items[selectedFile.DriveItem.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync())
                {
                    var driveItemFile = System.IO.File.Create(driveItemPath);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    stream.CopyTo(driveItemFile);
                    driveItemFile.Close(); //also a stream which needs to be Dispose()d.
                }
                DisplayAlert("Download", selectedFile.DriveItem.Name + " successfully downloaded", "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DOWNLOAD FAILED WITH: " + ex.Message);
                DisplayAlert("ERROR", selectedFile.DriveItem.Name + " failed with: " + ex.Message, "OK");
            }
            

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it that specific file that fails, or is it that any subsequent attempt fails? ie. First file always downloads regardless of which one, 2nd attempt always fails.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  the file was hidden for some reason.  I was ripping my hair out and decided to view all hidden files too in windows explorer.  and sure enough it popped up.

Comment: Usually happens when you take the time to write out a good question.  Gald you got past the problem.  Cheers

Comment: @hijinxbassist thanks for being understanding man!  ouf.

Comment: It looks the hidden file cause the problem, and you have found the reason, could you mind self answer this thread?